# How can I best check if A xor B are null?

Tags: c#, null, boolean-logic, xor

What is the best way to check if only A is null or only B is null?  I have been trying many different ways to find something that feels clean, and this is how convoluted it has gotten:

```
bool CheckForNull(object a, object b)
{
    if(a == null && b == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(a == null || b == null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

My best (and the most obvious) version is:

```
bool CheckForNull(object a, object b)
{
    return a == null && b != null || a != null && b == null;
}
```

But I don't really like that either.  (Sure I could add parenthesis...)

Is there a standard way of doing this that I never learned?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What about this:

```
return (a == null) != (b == null);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need/want to use xor, you could use:

```
return (a == null) ^ (b == null);
```

but for that to work, `true` has to evaluate to the same 'value'.

But in this case, I think I would keep it as simple as possible. Your second version doesn't look so bad actually:

```
return a == null && b != null || a != null && b == null;
```

and there is a possibility of an *early exit*. (and if lucky, the compiler might even optimize this to be executed in parallel (instruction pipelining)).

Comment: True has to evaluate to the same value? Watcha mean? When is true not equal to true?

Comment: @Evorlor Depending on the language, anything that is not zero can evaluate to true (0 is false, all else is true). So if your left 'true' is 1 and the right one is 2, the xor won't work as expected.

Comment: The question has the c# tag. No need wondering which language.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the xor operator

```
bool CheckForNull(object a, object b)
{
    return (a == null ^ b == null);
}
```